# How to list out the numbers in the given interval using Python?

Tags: python, list

I have a table with column A. How can I create a table like table B (9000 combined with all the numbers in the interval)? The data type is string.

| A |
| --- |
| 9000(1-4) |
| 9001(1-4) |

| B |
| --- |
| 90001 |
| 90002 |
| 90003 |
| 90004 |
| 90011 |
| 90012 |
| 90013 |
| 90014 |

Comment: Python? R? Pick one! Are you using pandas? Looks like you'll need to write some code to parse the `(1-4)` interval into two columns containing `1` and `4` separately.

Comment: in Python, you can do `range(90001, 90005)`. Dunno about R

Comment: Where's the code you've already tried? Your question lacks information: how are these tables stored? Are they strings? Is that HTML?

Answer (score 0):

This would be what you need.

```
a, b = [int(x[0]) for x in '9000(1-4)'.split('(', maxsplit=1)[1].split('-')]
l = [ 9000+x for x in range(a, b+1) ]
print(l)
```